# How do I handle users uploading webp images?

Tags: node.js, webp

So, I have a simple uploader that lets users upload images and then view them somewhere. Now the issue is that many users have started uploading webp images (they just download images from certain sites visited via a supported browser like Chrome and are served webp images) and then when they try to view those in browsers like Safari, they don't show up.

What I'd like to do is have some sort of processing step that would let me convert the webp to jpeg or png before uploading it to S3.

Or would it be better to discourage webp uploads?

This link amply describes what I'm facing: http://www.cnet.com/news/facebook-tries-googles-webp-image-format-users-squawk/

Note: My server runs node with express.

Comment: If i am reading this correctly, i would say that converting webP files to JPG or PNG images before uploading to S3 would be a better option. i also encourage you to upload the webP file to S3 in order to maintain everything in a single handled file repository.

Comment: Since webP can handle both pngs and jpegs, is there a way to know what the original format was and convert to that? A solution that's node-friendly?